# Flutter - Waiting for a variable to take on a specific value

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream, udp

I am actually new to flutter and started developing my fist app to control my IoT device (ESP8266).

Im currently struggling to wait for a variable to take on a specific value.
In Detail: im sending an udp broadcast to get the IP address of my ESP device. I already managed it to receive my own broadcast and the answer of the ESP afterwards.
So the connection is established.

The thing is: i receive my own broadcast *before* i receive the correct answer i want and my function already returned the IP address of my smartphone.

How do i solve the problem to wait until the address of the message i received is different than the ip address of my smartphone?

```
class EspDeviceUdp {
  /// Port to send UDP messages to.
  int port = 2390;

  /// IP address of the smartphone.
  InternetAddress ownIP;

  /// IP address of the target device.
  InternetAddress tarIP = InternetAddress('0.0.0.0');

  EspDeviceUdp({required this.ownIP});

  /// Tries to find the esp in network while using udp broadcast
  Future<InternetAddress?> getEspIp() async {
    // variables to store tx data and wifi config
    Uint8List tXData = Uint8List(12);
    String ipAdr = "255.255.255.255";
    port = 2390;
    int id = udpIdHandshakeRequest, data1 = 0, data2 = 0, data3 = 0;
    bool ipDetected = false;
    InternetAddress? retVal;

    // build tx data stream
    buildUdpStream(tXData, id, data1, data2, data3);

    // Stream variables for future listening on incoming ip addresses.
    StreamController<InternetAddress?> controller = StreamController();

    // send udp broadcast and receive ip address from the esp device
    RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port)
        .then((RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
      udpSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;
      udpSocket.listen((e) {
        controller.sink.add(udpSocket.receive()?.address);
      });
      udpSocket.send(tXData, InternetAddress(ipAdr), port);
    });

    retVal = await _getIp(controller);
    return retVal;
  }

  Future<InternetAddress?> _getIp(
    StreamController<InternetAddress?> ctrl) async {
      InternetAddress? retVal = InternetAddress('0.0.0.0');

      // wait for a value which is different than our own IP address
      await for (final value in ctrl.stream) {
        if (value != ownIP) {
          retVal = value;
          ctrl.sink.close();
        }
      }
    return retVal;
  }

  /// Building the tx stream to config the esp device via udp.
  /// [txDataList] given as pointer is the list where the stream will be built in.
  /// [id] is the command which has to be sent.
  /// [data1], [data2], [data3] are the data packages. Meaning depends on the id.
  void buildUdpStream(
      Uint8List txDataList, int id, int data1, int data2, int data3) {
    // id
    txDataList[0] = id & 0xFF;
    txDataList[1] = (id >> 8) & 0xFF;
    // data1
    txDataList[2] = data1 & 0xFF;
    txDataList[3] = (data1 >> 8) & 0xFF;
    // data2
    txDataList[4] = data2 & 0xFF;
    txDataList[5] = (data2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
    // data3
    txDataList[6] = data3 & 0xFF;
    txDataList[7] = (data3 >> 8) & 0xFF;
    // reserved
    txDataList[8] = 0;
    txDataList[9] = 0;
    // reserved
    txDataList[10] = 0;
    txDataList[11] = 0;
  }
}
```

First thing i do is to read out the IP address of my smartphone. Then everytime i hit a button *getEspIp()* gets called.

So here is the output i get when hitting the button twice:

```
I/flutter (14571): smart phone ip address: InternetAddress('192.168.2.103', IPv4)
I/flutter (14571): IP from Esp8266 = 192.168.2.228
D/ViewRootImpl@403a26[MainActivity](14571): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@403a26[MainActivity](14571): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/flutter (14571): smart phone ip address: InternetAddress('192.168.2.103', IPv4)
E/flutter (14571): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add event after closing
E/flutter (14571): #0      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:595:24)
E/flutter (14571): #1      _StreamSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:867:13)
E/flutter (14571): #2      EspDeviceUdp.getClockIp.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:udp_testing/wifi.dart:113:25)
E/flutter (14571): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1442:13)
E/flutter (14571): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (14571): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (14571): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (14571): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (14571): #8      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
E/flutter (14571): #9      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
E/flutter (14571): #10     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
E/flutter (14571): #11     new _RawDatagramSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2403:33)
E/flutter (14571): #12     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1322:14)
E/flutter (14571): #13     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (14571): #14     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (14571): 
I/flutter (14571): IP from Esp8266 = 192.168.2.228
```

I guess the error occures because i close my stream. But it wont leave _getIp() unless i close the stream. Im probably not on the right way with using a stream?

Comment: For those who have the same question or issue, take a closer look at 'Completer' in flutter. I finally found what i was looking for.